# How can I generate and publish raster images?

Tags: raster, interpolation, server, heat-map, kriging

I have several hundred groups of data points (in lat/lng format). I want to generate heat maps for each group using kriging or similar interpolations and then display the generated raster images on a map server. What will be the best solution? I can't use ESRI products as they're not free. I know a little bit of Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Fusion Tables](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/) is a free product, and has the ability to make heat maps from points.

You would load your lat/long points into the fusion table, specify that the fields denoted lat/long, and check the Heatmap option. There's a good example [here](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/heatmap.html).

Note that there's no control over how the heatmap is generated, so it may not suit your advanced purposes given that you mentioned kriging, Python, etc.

Comment: I kind of remember the heatmap generated by google fusion is by point density; that is, no z-value is used.  I hope there is a kriging/interpolation library that I call using Python.  In addition, I don't know what is a good way to store the images and display them.  I hope there's a framework that is easy to configure.  I'm kinda new in GIS.  Thanks!

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/open-source-methods-for-kriging might help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Python program [here](http://www.sethoscope.net/heatmap/). It gives some pretty heatmap visualizations. But the output is not geo-referenced. You can them as images are even videos.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a combination of tools. R sounds like the best fit for your interpolations and raster formatting. As far as web display is concerned, you have options that include a PostGIS/postGreSQL stack for a 'true' web mapping service. D3.js has good mapping tools ([including tile support](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4150951)) that may be appropriate if you're trying to just get something out there fast.